How to setup Windows local development for a Foundry python code repository
I am following local development instructions here and hitting a "The system cannot find the file specified" error when running .\gradlew.bat condaDevelop
Re-running the command with --info shows that the error comes from this command being executed:
C:\Users\proggeo\.conda-installs\mamba-installer8-win-64\attempt\condabin\mamba.bat install --json --dry-run --mkdir -q python<3.11 python transforms-expectations transforms==1.1078.0 black transforms-verbs setuptools transforms=1.* -p build\tmp\runVersions
Defining explicit python version in meta.yaml file doesn't help as the command keeps the "<3.11" requirement:
C:\Users\proggeo\.conda-installs\mamba-installer8-win-64\attempt\condabin\mamba.bat install --json --dry-run --mkdir -q python<3.11 transforms-expectations transforms==1.1078.0 black transforms-verbs setuptools python=3.10 transforms=1.* -p build\tmp\runVersions
It seems the issue is with the "python<3.11" notation, as I can reproduce it by calling the same mamba.bat file.
PS C:\Users\proggeo\python-repo> C:\Users\proggeo\.conda-installs\mamba-installer8-win-64\attempt\condabin\mamba.bat install python<3.11
The system cannot find the file specified.
PS C:\Users\proggeo\python-repo> C:\Users\proggeo\.conda-installs\mamba-installer8-win-64\attempt\condabin\mamba.bat install python=3.11

Looking for: ['python=3.11']

pkgs/main/win-64 (check zst)                        Checked  0.2s
pkgs/main/noarch (check zst)                        Checked  0.0s
pkgs/r/win-64 (check zst)                           Checked  0.0s
pkgs/r/noarch (check zst)                           Checked  0.0s
pkgs/msys2/win-64 (check zst)                       Checked  0.0s
pkgs/msys2/noarch (check zst)                       Checked  0.0s

It looks like this old mamba issue which was supposed to be fixed already many versions ago: https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1561.
Conda/mamba versions are following (Foundry repo version is "transforms-python" : "1.717.0"):
C:\Users\proggeo\.conda-installs\mamba-installer8-win-64\attempt\condabin\mamba.bat --version
mamba 1.5.1
conda 23.5.2

This reproduced on multiple computers, including a fresh Azure Virtual Desktop, with only Java 17, Git and VS Code installed.
Did anybody hit this issue before? Any workarounds?
